# Store App data Even After app uninstalls

Tags: android, sqlite

A am developing an android app which is based on coupon scratching. it synchs all the data from the server with php backend. after syncing user scratches the coupon and the code was shown with a code he enters a mobile no and submits it. after submitting he gets to see the prize money behind that scratched code. After first time syncing no internet is necessory. after scratching all the coupon the user updates the data  stored in sqlite database, to the online server and the prize money is transfered to respective mobile no. the problem is when user scratch the coupon and knows the money behind the code then he will uninstall the app without updating the scratched data into server and install it again and now he knows the prize money behind each code so he can fill his mobile no on the higher prize money. i cannot synch the data for each scratch because the main requirement of this app is offline working. i have to do it per 25 or 50 scratches. how to save the sqlite database even after the app gets unistalled?

Comment: `how to save the sqlite database even after the app gets unistalled?` I dont know about it. In case the answer is `no`, my idea is to create an encrypted file and store your sensitive data in that file.

Comment: there will be no use for encryption because after user submits the data he sees how much money was behind the code. he will uninstall the the app without updating the scratched data to server now he fill the high prize money code with his mobile no! the main solution will be somehow store the data after app gets unistalled!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend any business model where you send me money based on the state of my phone.  It's my phone.  I control it's state.  Your app is just a guest.  Far more sensible for you to keep your own records on your own server of who's been paid and who hasn't.

Comment: its an app for a MNC company he gives the app to his distributors and his customers scratched the coupon on distributors tablet and win money but distributor could use the high prize code for his own benefit. is there no way to store the data after app uninstall, bcoz i have seen app with this feature!

Comment: you have to store a field in the user table on server for checking that  if the user is already registered or not also store what level user has cleared and sync the app with server.

Comment: i am doing that! Problem is- i am designing the app so that the user have to update the data only once in a day. so between this period if app uninstalls i don't want to lose the data of that day

Comment: Even if google allowed you to distribute an app that didn't properly clean up after itself when uninstalled there is nothing you can do that a well informed user, motivated by your money, couldn't undo since it is their phone.  You might be able to hide data somewhere for a while but sooner or later someone will make a youtube video telling everyone how to clean their phone of your data.

Comment: You could pffer the ability to **export/import** the data to a CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SharedPreferencesBackupHelper . It will backup some of the preference . Please check the documentation from developer site

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/SharedPreferencesBackupHelper.html

As I told you just store the the level and phone number into preference.

Hope It will help.